# how can I convert mp3 to wav using php code without external library or application

Tags: php, mp3, wav

I am trying to generate waveform for mp3 files, and found that it is possible using php code to generate waveform for wav files, but not mp3. I need to convert mp3 to wav, but also it is not possible to install ffmpeg or lame on shared hosting, is there any other solutions like php based conversion?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. But you can use a SAAS platform to help you with that. maybe you can try http://www.encoding.com/ or http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/.

Comment: thank you Mircea, what it is not possible ? I mean why it is very difficult to do this with php ?

Comment: @FirasAbdAlrahman Codecs are extremely complicated.  Far more complicated than buying a better hosting service.  You want to spend 5 years reverse engineering a codec when you could just spend $5/mo. on a VPS where you can install whatever you want?

Comment: @Brad great, so the reason is there is no codec written in php which should be used to make conversion

Comment: @FirasAbdAlrahman Yes, as far as I know nobody has made a PHP implementation of MP3.  (Even if they did, it would be very inefficient.)  And, MP3 raw data itself is based on the frequency domain, not the time domain, so it absolutely must be decoded if you want a time domain graph.